# Don't say "Comment if you're trying to respond to an answer." when there's no answer, after clicking on "answer your question"

Tags: feature-request, comments, self-answer

Don't say "Comment if you're trying to respond to an answer." when there's no answer, after clicking on "answer your question":

[image: Se]

I think if we remove information that doesn't apply in the current context, then the user is more likely to read the information that does apply.

Comment: Why does the alt text just say 'Se'?

Comment: @BSMP due to the annoying focus steal / forced cursor relocation after image upload. I was typing some text containing Se when finally the image was done uploading. Just a matter of time before some non-neutral word unintentionally slips in.

Answer (score -4):

I think it's a bad idea to obscure a useful piece of information to a newcomer. There might come a time when the new user uses *another* way to communicate with the community after having this pop-up on an unanswered question, and without that advice for later he's probably going to comment directly on the question itself or post his response as an answer. It is not worth hiding that info, without it the new user might end up asking us easy-peasy questions that could easily be answered by pop-ups from the system, such as "where's the help center?"

It could be quite unlikely, but sometimes a user could come and ask a question and would decide to actively stay with the community afterwards. That could be a time for something like this to happen.

Comment: "bad idea to obscure a useful piece of information to a newcomer.": I think if we remove information that doesn't apply in the current context, then the user is more likely to read the information that does apply. (Same, no idea why someone downvoted your answer, that doesn't strike me as constructive).

Comment: I'm confused that both your answer and my question are getting downvoted, as they have share a different opinion. I don't get why people want to express with their downvotes. Maybe just downvoting for the sake of it?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Me too, if both of the two are being downvoted then that means they likely have a *different* opinion about this request which they can simply post as an answer. Yet there are no other answers.